# What's wrong passing this enumeration to CTOR?

Tags: c++, class, enums, init

My [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5663f7d42cbeb173):

```
#include <iostream>

enum EnvelopeMultiPointsType {
    ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL = 0,
    ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_KICK_PITCH,
    kNumEnvelopeMultiPointsTypes
};

class EnvelopeMultiPoints
{
public:
    EnvelopeMultiPoints(EnvelopeMultiPointsType type) : mType(type) { 
        std::cout << mType << std::endl;
    }
    ~EnvelopeMultiPoints() { };

private:
    EnvelopeMultiPointsType mType;
};

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { };
    ~Test() { };

private:
    EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv(EnvelopeMultiPointsType::ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL);
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
}
```

It seems I cannot init a class with that enum. Not sure why. What am I missing here?

Online compiler says *no type named 'ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL' in 'EnvelopeMultiPointsType'*, but it is declared above.

Comment: It's because you're using an enum value as an argument. That's like writing `EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv(0);` as a function declaration. Instead, use `EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv(EnvelopeMultiPointsType a_type);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When initializing a member variable inline like you want to do, then you have to use *brace or equal* initialization.

I.e. either

```
// Use braces
EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv{EnvelopeMultiPointsType::ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL};
```

Or

```
// Use equal
EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv = EnvelopeMultiPointsType::ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL;
```

It's a way to prevent the ambiguity of [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Read e.g. [this member initialization reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv(EnvelopeMultiPointsType::ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

gets parsed as a declaration of a function `mEnv` that returns `EnvelopeMultiPoints` and takes 1 variable of the non-existent `EnvelopeMultiPointsType::ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL` type as a single unnamed argument.

Initialize your variable like this instead:

```
EnvelopeMultiPoints mEnv = EnvelopeMultiPointsType::ENVELOPE_MULTI_POINTS_TYPE_NORMAL;
```